# How to repair cleared ACL?

Tags: permission

On a recent support call I was asked to run the following command:

```
sudo chmod -R -N ~/Library/Containers/com.someco.someapp/
```

but on further examination I see that that directory contains a subfolder with
the following contents:

```
...
lrwxr-xr-x   1 Orome  staff     19 Feb 27  2019 Desktop@ -> ../../../../Desktop
lrwxr-xr-x   1 Orome  staff     21 Feb 27  2019 Downloads@ -> ../../../../Downloads
lrwxr-xr-x   1 Orome  staff     18 Feb 27  2019 Movies@ -> ../../../../Movies
lrwxr-xr-x   1 Orome  staff     17 Feb 27  2019 Music@ -> ../../../../Music
lrwxr-xr-x   1 Orome  staff     20 Feb 27  2019 Pictures@ -> ../../../../Pictures
...
```

What did this command do? What ACL's have I removed? If I run into trouble is there a simple way to restore things to be as they should be?

---

I'd like to believe that I have nothing to worry about (that [no symbolic links are followed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/465259/4395)); but it's unclear to then why this would have been output by the command:

```
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file .com.apple.containermanagerd.metadata.plist: Operation not permitted
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file AddressBook: Operation not permitted
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file Filters: No such file or directory
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file Calendars: Operation not permitted
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file com.apple.security.plist: No such file or directory
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file com.apple.security_common.plist: No such file or directory
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file KeyBindings: No such file or directory
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file People: No such file or directory
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file Mail: Operation not permitted
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file Compositions: No such file or directory
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file Input Methods: No such file or directory
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file Downloads: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 2):

There should be no effect on the symlinked directories. From the man page:

> `-P`    If the `-R` option is specified, no symbolic links are followed.  This is the default.

Comment: So `-P` is the default and thus by default no symbolic links are followed?

Comment: (I ask partly because I got a bunch of asks to allow Terminal access to all kinds of things and allowed at least a few. Not sure why it would have asked if it wasn't following the links.)

Comment: Also added some details about messages I got to the OP.